# How do I put a System.Windows.Forms.Panel in an Excel document using VBA?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, com

I have a visual component written in C# that extends a System.Windows.Forms.Panel, I can change this to System.Windows.Forms.Control or similar if needed.

I have an application written as macros in an Excel 2005 document using VBA.

I want to put my C# (.NET) control in the VBA application in some way, but I can't find any solution.

I have tried to do it using COM and managed to create objects but I can't find any way to make them visible. Should I implement some OLE interface? Can't find anything about how to create an OLE object in .NET.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think that there ever was an Excel 2005. Choose from: 2003 (Windows), 2004 (Mac) or 2007 (Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ComVisible Attribute to true (default is false)

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

check your `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: I have managed to make my classes COM visible. The problem is to insert the control in an Excel document using VBA.